# Why would you want to change the log_msg_size from syslog-ng's default of 64k?

Tags: logging, syslog, syslog-ng

Per the [syslog-ng admin guide](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/administration-guide/log-msg-size), the `log_msg_size` defaults to 64k (65536 bytes)

However, I have seen some sample syslog-ng config files (like [this one](https://gist.github.com/anthonygtellez/7edd44cf5571609c70b4)) that drop this to <18k (18192 bytes)

Why would you want to change the default behavior - especially, why would you want to *reduce* it?

Answer (score 1):

The main reasoning behind this is resource limitations or legacy use-cases where destinations may not support long messages.

`log_msg_size()` limits the maximum accepted size of incoming messages.
Using it together with the `log-fifo-size()` and `log-iw-size()` options, you can roughly estimate the maximum possible memory usage of syslog-ng, so it helps to set an upper limit on memory consumption.

Comment: OK ... but syslog-ng is distinctly *not* a "legacy use-case": in fact, it's meant to *replace* those legacy syslog collectors :)

Comment: Indeed. But when syslog-ng is operating as a forwarder, it might make sense. Other than that, it's all about limiting resource allocations.

Comment: wouldn't have thought of using it as a syslog forwarder :)

Comment: @warren: Any other recommendations for a syslog forwarder?  A common setup is to have a local syslog collector where all hosts of one organizational unit send their logs to and where the local admins have access to for debugging, usually keeping the logs for a week or month. Those local syslog servers also forward the logs to a central syslog server which stores all received logs for as long as law requires them to be stored, typically something between 6 months and 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

Another case is that older Syslog-NG versions (e.g. as the one distributed with RHEL 7) had much lower defaults (4 or 8 kB come to my mind). There you usually want to raise that limit. Actually if you saw these 18kB on an old server, it might be that it was actually raised, not lowered.